# What is the timeline for UK postdoc applications in math?

Tags: mathematics, application, postdocs, united-kingdom

I (a graduate student in math at a US university) have heard a lot of advice about applying for postdocs in math at US universities. I've been told when applications for jobs and NSF are due, when you can expect hear back, and how long you have to make a decision.

What is the timeline for applications to UK universities for math postdocs?

Comment: Postdocs in math don't exist in the UK. Postdocs in *maths*, however... ;)

Answer (score 2):

The timeline varies from one place to another. Some Universities will compose a shortlist in a week after the deadline and call candidates in for an interview a couple of weeks later. Following the interview, the final decision can be made in a couple of days.

However, it is not uncommon for the shortlisting to take several months. For various reasons, the final decision after the interview can also take longer. I received my postdoc offer ~3 months after the interview date.